# Query for menus in backend (BE)

Tags: menus, admin

I want to create a simple plugin (already started) to have in one place recurring tasks (for me as webdesigner) e.g. take site offline, set backend icon, don't show updates and so on...

Now I want to hide some menus for my clients in BE and I am asking if someone knows a query to get all existing menus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean like: settings, dashboard, post, page, design, comments, etc..

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Admin menus are more or less constructed on the fly rather than created persistently. This might be very tricking, depending on when and how you want to access it.

Comment: I've seen the plugin "Adminimize" - and there are all menus shown - even my own created. I don't want to depend on other plugins and I am not that "PRO" to extract the functions from that plug. So I thought backend-menu-pages (or whatever I should call them) are somehow registered and in that case -> can be queried.

Comment: If I can query them, I could make a own function to either "unregister" them (via 'remove_menu_page()') or at least hide them via CSS. First option I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation menus are technically terms, but there is pretty rich API around theme to abstract that away.

[`wp_get_nav_menus()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_nav_menus/) should do it. :)

Comment: I mean like: settings, dashboard, post, page, design, comments, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I was looking for in [wpengineer.com](http://wpengineer.com/2233/remove-menu-item-in-wordpress-admin-panel/)

It's made by the $menu as global variable.